# Remove product A from cart if product B is removed from cart on WooCoomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a rule where Product A is automatically added to the cart if product B is added to the cart. I use this code to achieve that:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', function( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) 
{
    //If added product ID is 67 then also add product with an ID of 15
    if ( 67 == $product_id ) {
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 15 );
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

I want the same kind of rule, when removing the products from the cart.

E.g. product A is automatically removed from the cart if product B is removed or not present in the cart. Basically, product B cannot be bought without product A and vice versa.

I've found something similar but for product categories, but are not able to translate it to product ID's: 
 [Remove other products if certain product category is present on WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70232179/remove-other-products-if-certain-product-category-is-present-on-woocommerce-chec/70232955#70232955)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten this based on a snippet I once used on a project.

To listen to the moment when a product is removed from the cart use the hook `woocommerce_remove_cart_item` like this:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_remove_cart_item', 'jhall_remove_product_from_cart', 10, 2 );

    /**
     * Remove Product ID 15 when Product ID 67 is removed from the cart
     *
     * @param $item_key
     * @param $cart
     * @return $item_key
     */
    function jhall_remove_product_from_cart( $item_key, $cart ){
      
      //Get the ID of the product removed
      $removed_id = $cart->cart_contents[$item_key]['product_id'];
      //If the Product ID is 67
      if( $removed_id === 67 ){
          //You need a cart key for the product you want to remove
          $remove_from_cart_product_id = $cart->generate_cart_id( 15 );
          //Remove Product ID 15 from the cart
          $cart->remove_cart_item( $remove_from_cart_product_id );
    }
```

Note that relying on Product IDs can be problematic. I usually prefer to avoid this in favor of a product slug or other identifier that can be reliable across installations where this code will run.