# Add or remove WooCommerce product from cart if another product is added or removed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I found this here: [Remove product A from cart if product B is removed from cart on WooCoomerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76540462/remove-product-a-from-cart-if-product-b-is-removed-from-cart-on-woocoomerce) which works to add Product B when Product A is added to the cart. I'm using WPCode Snippet.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', function( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) 
{
    //If added product ID is 67 then also add product with an ID of 15
    if ( 67 == $product_id ) {
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 15 );
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

However, the answer given doesn't work when both codes are active. I have them a two separate code snippets. When I add Product A, it's the only item in the cart. It doesn't add Product B now. Do both codes need to be in one snippet (possibly)? Or simply doesn't work. Also, I need to use ID's because I've created an eLearning site which is not WooCommerce (Product A) but Product B is a WooCommerce product. It uses the WooCommerce cart to checkout.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_remove_cart_item', 'jhall_remove_product_from_cart', 10, 2 );

    /**
     * Remove Product ID 15 when Product ID 67 is removed from the cart
     *
     * @param $item_key
     * @param $cart
     * @return $item_key
     */
    function jhall_remove_product_from_cart( $item_key, $cart ){
      
      //Get the ID of the product removed
      $removed_id = $cart->cart_contents[$item_key]['product_id'];
      //If the Product ID is 67
      if( $removed_id === 67 ){
          //You need a cart key for the product you want to remove
          $remove_from_cart_product_id = $cart->generate_cart_id( 15 );
          //Remove Product ID 15 from the cart
          $cart->remove_cart_item( $remove_from_cart_product_id );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code replacement:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'action_before_cart_calculate_totals');
function action_before_cart_calculate_totals( $cart ) {
    if ((is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')))
        return;

    $targeted_product_id = 67; // Define the targeted product ID
    $linked_product_id   = 15; // Define the linked product ID that should be added (complementary)
    $linked_item_key = $targeted_found = false; // Initialized variables

    // Check cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
        // Check if our targeted product is in cart
        if ( $item['product_id'] == $targeted_product_id ) {
            $targeted_found = true;
        } 
        // Check if the complementary product is in cart
        elseif ( $item['product_id'] == $linked_product_id ) {
            $linked_item_key = $item_key;
        }
    }

    if ( $targeted_found && ! $linked_item_key ) {
        $cart->add_to_cart( $linked_product_id ); // Add to cart the complementary product
    } elseif ( ! $targeted_found && $linked_item_key ) {
        $cart->remove_cart_item($linked_item_key); // Remove from cart the complementary product
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.